# PrestaShop Webservice not returning product created by Webservice

Tags: prestashop

I have successfully used the PrestaShop Webservice to create a new product from our custom application. The product gets created using the product XML schema and I can view it in the Catalog.

However, I cannot retrieve the product using the Webservice filtering on the 'reference' field. An empty  node is returned, but I can retrieve it by ID.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this might be? Do I need to set something within the product via the Webservice to make it filterable?

Regards
Andrew

Comment: What is your Prestashop version? How is your Webservice URL (filtering by reference) constructed?

Comment: Have you set product visibility?

Comment: PrestaShop version 1.6.1.18. I've been trying the URL: https://prestashop.xxxxx.dev/api/products?filter[reference]=[my-ref-text] and the visibility is: <visibility><![CDATA[ both ]]></visibility>

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem after debugging the WPS Webservice code down to the function getFilteredObjectList() in classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php line 1199.

My product reference was being created as ' my-text-ref ' (with the space either side), so my filter for 'my-text-ref' without spaces was not found.

This is because in my XML used to create the product I had:

I've changed this to:

And it all works!